Generating PDF with mixed content - Arabic is always reversed
I have been trying to generate pdf documents with mixed Arabic and English content and I always end up with Arabic text reversed. I have tried itext (without PDFCalligraph), pPDFBox with same output. Today I came across OpenHtmltoPdf and its sandbox and I was able to inject simple content into the html and got text in Arabic in correct way. I found the source for the sandbox and used it as example to generate my content but it doesn't matter what I do - my text is reversed.
Here's my HTML content:
<html>
<head>

    <title>Test for mixed directions content</title>

    <style>
        table {
            width: 80%;
            border-collapse: collapse;
            padding: 6px;
        }

        td {
            border: 1px solid #ccc;
            padding: 8px;
            vertical-align: middle;
        }

        [lang="ar"] {
            font-family: "arabic", serif;

        }

    </style>

</head>
<body dir="auto">

<p lang="ar">
مرحبًا، فلنبدأ الاختبار!
</p>

<table>
    <tr>
        <td lang="ar">الزهور</td>
        <td>flowers</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td lang="ar">الاشجار</td>
        <td>trees</td>
    </tr>
</table>

<br />End of test.

</body>
</html>


I noticed that when copy-pasted here, it looks reversed, too, but it looks right in IDE:

And here's the code that generates the pdf:
try (ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream()) {
            String templatePath = "classpath:templates/test/index.html";
            File htmlFile = ResourceUtils.getFile(templatePath);
            String htmlContent = new String(Files.readAllBytes(htmlFile.toPath()), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

            PdfRendererBuilder builder = new PdfRendererBuilder();
            builder.withHtmlContent(htmlContent, null);

            String fontPath = "classpath:templates/test/Amiri-Regular.ttf";
            File fontFile = ResourceUtils.getFile(fontPath);
            builder.useFont(fontFile, "arabic");

            builder.useUnicodeBidiSplitter(new ICUBidiSplitter.ICUBidiSplitterFactory());
            builder.useUnicodeBidiReorderer(new ICUBidiReorderer());
            // setting RTL does not change anything
            builder.defaultTextDirection(BaseRendererBuilder.TextDirection.LTR);

            builder.useFastMode();
            builder.toStream(outputStream);
            builder.run();

            // return content
          
        } 
    }

I must be overlooking something fairly simple or doing something else wrong. Java 23, Mac OS, the Amiri font I use comes from Google fonts - I tried other fonts, like Rubik and NotoSansArabic with the same outcome:

